# Toggle the Navigation Drawer via the stock Action Bar title with highlight

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to mimic the Google Play Store application ActionBar: when you **click on the title** of the application, the **title itself is highlighted** (normally with a blue background in JB) **and the Navigation Drawer opens**/closes.

I'm using the Navigation-Drawer sample application available on Google Developers website ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)) and it doesn't do the same. There is no blue background when you touch the title and also the "click zone" on the title text is only about 3-4 characters of lenght as width. On the Play Store or Gmail applications you can touch even the end of the string and the Navigation Drawer will open. See this screenshot for reference:

[image: Screenshot comparing ActionBar highlight]

So, I'm looking for tips or even links to source code of other Android applications that have this feature and also:

- Use standard ActionBar (no ActionBarCompact or ActionBarSherlock)
- Target API 14+
- Preferably do not use any external library (does Play Store use them?)

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm testing on the emulator using Android 4.2.2.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I don't know why, but somewhat I forgot to tell you. You were right, that behaviour occurs on Android < 4.3 while on Android >= 4.3 the title is fully clickable with highlight (same code running on newer OS). Please post this as an answer and I'll mark so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the title is included in the touch target for the drawer on Android 4.3 and Android 4.4 devices (unlike previous versions of Android where the title was not included) so you shouldn't have to do anything to get consistent touch targets.

Note that in Android 5.0 and Material Design, the navigation button is much larger (taking the place of the app icon) and the title is **not** included in the touch target. Updating to [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) will give you this new functionality and be consistent with Google apps across all API versions (although note that not all Google apps have fully followed the guidelines as of yet - a work in progress as they all move to using AppCompat)